# Success using 512GB SD cards in ST600s?

Tags: soundtrap, data-storage

Has anyone successfully used 512 GB SD cards in the Soundtrap 600s?  The spec sheet says it can take up to 4 of the 512 GB cards, but curious on the success rate of these vs the smaller 256 GB ones. It seems that bigger cards would result in less needed transitions between cards and possibly less chance of failure. -C

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please remember to phrase the title as an actual question that you (or someone else) would ask.

Answer (score 4):

512 GB cards work fine in ST600s in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

While not using Soundtrap, I simply would try it out.

There are a few reasons why the SD card size could matter:

- Higher density SD cards are still less reliable (manufacturing process) and more expensive.
- Only 256 GB cards were tested and special brand found with sufficient quality.
- higher density cards consume somewhat more current (not sure why, but most likely they are made for higher transfer speed).
- some hidden software limitation (a test will reveal).

If you try larger disks, please let us know the result.

I, myself, use 1TB uSD disks with my own ARU. (Transfer is, however, extremely long)